# ASP.NET MVC2 + CSS - how to refresh CSS?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem with CSS as I am changing it but I do not see changes! How to refresh it? I changed name of this css file and on the master.site there is written that he can not find ../../Site.css but when I start this project it still see the old one version somehow. What should I do? as clean and build solution is not working :/.

Do you have any way to refresh it?
Thanks!

EDIT:

```
<link href="../../Content/Siteeeee.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: What does the portion of your master page containing the reference to the stylesheet look like?

Comment: <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Are you sure you're editing /Content/Site.css ?

Comment: Your css files are different.

Comment: Yes I am changing good one. It is really strange! As when I changed the name it was working, when I removed link it stop working what is obvious, when I added it back (even if he could not find this name site.css as I changed it to siteeeee.css it was working correctly - it is keeping it somewhere in memory this stylesheet but I do not know how to clear it. I had to create another css with different name and change the head link and now it changed the css. Crazy one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear you browser's cache. Or do CTRL + F5.

What I usually do is to set expiry headers on release builds only and have no caching on debug builds. In that way during development all the resource files are always fetched from the server.

You might want to apply versioning in release builds so the users can cache each version for ever.